# Why I'm getting cached data from server?

Tags: http, nginx, cpanel

I'm system administrator and one of my colleague (PHP developer, uses  `yii2` framework) moved all files to another hosting (from A to B). I changed all domain "A" records value to B server's IP via DNSManager.  Didn't touch other records.

Problem:

- Everything works fine, but client application receives old data from server.
- I tried change sample data on DataBase(MySQL) manually, and still getting old data.

After minute (or less then), server responses actual data for the same request.

Where is the problem (Apache, DNS, Yii2)? How to solve it?

Comment: cache was randomly

Comment: Please share more details. Why is this tagged with PHP, but does not contain any such code?

Comment: @NicoHaase ok, I removed php from tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: nginx control panel]

I've found , the Nginx caches every request, and returns old cached data on every
quick repeated requests. So I turned **off** Proxy Cache from Nginx **Cache Management**.

Comment: don't forget to disable cache from Yii2